# Parse JSON in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need Parse to json in angularJS.

```
 {
    "status": true,
    "previous_status": "",
    "pass": true,
    "name": "N/A",
    "payment_date": "March 5, 2018 - 1:54 pm",
    "address": "N/A",
    "city": "N/A",
    "state": "N/A",
    "country": "N/A",
    "checksum": "1009-1",
    "custom_fields": [
        [
            "Ticket Type",
            "Friday ticket - 2018"
        ],
        [
            "Buyer Name",
            "Jhon Doe"
        ],
        [
            "Buyer E-mail",
            "demo@email.com"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I make **ng-repeat** but show this in **HTML**

["Ticket Type","Friday ticket"]

["Buyer Name","Jhon Doe"]

["Buyer E-mail","demo@email.com"]

I need same like this.

**Ticket Type:** Friday ticket

Code snippet :

```
function fetch() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    timeout: 6000
  }).then(
    function(result) {
      $scope.tickets = result.data;
    }
  );

}
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet of your code.

Comment: do something like `{{custom_field[0]}}: {{custom_field[1]}}`. Makes me think it should be an object and not an array

Comment: @HassanImam Ready :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map that array before to render it into the HTML.

*This alternative doesn't mutate the original data.*

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.custom_fields = [
    ["Ticket Type", "Friday ticket - 2018"],
    ["Buyer Name", "Jhon Doe"],
    ["Buyer E-mail", "demo@email.com"]
  ];
  $scope.mapped = $scope.custom_fields.map(function(c) {
    return {
      title: c[0],
      text: c[1]
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  <p ng-repeat='entry in mapped'>
    <b>{{entry.title}}</b>: {{entry.text}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! forget to remove the original email, you can change it from your answer. Maybe use the same one that I just placed.

Comment: @JuanDavid done!